# DialogFlow button in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, dialogflow-es

I am creating an simple chatbot app using Android studio, is button available in Android studio? (without integrate with other platform) If so, is there any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is and here is the documentation for it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button